# How to create a Custom List in Sharepoint 2013 from a Template using SPServices REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, template

I have made two custom list templates for 2013 and I want to create lists using those templates Dynamically.
Something like using a page in which I choose the name and description of the custom list and create it.

I have no clue on how to write the code.

If this is not possible, can I create an Empty Custom List and Copy its file and rename-it?

What should I do, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to use REST/custom code? Are you not able to create new list using the custom template from "Add an app" option?

Comment: I want to have a simple textbox in which the user writes a name (let's say, "Model1"). Then, I add that name inside a list (a "MODELS List") and create two more lists: Model1_Template_1 and Model1_Template_2 Dinamically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Create two links linking to Create App choice under Web Content:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx?#qry=CUSTOM
```

where CUSTOM is title of the created Template

Here from the list can user which have appropriate permissions create new List or Library from these templates.

or you can create link directing exactly to creating new App:

1. Open SharePoint in Chrome
2. Go to Site Content > Add an App > Choose your template
3. When Pop-Up window with Pick a Name and Advanced Options, right-click on this Pop-Up Window and select **View Frame Source**
4. Copy URL from Address bar - https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/new.aspx?FeatureId=%7B00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100%7D&ListTemplate=100&IsDlg=1
5. You can use it in IFrame or as Link for creating selected Template on this Site

It will looks like:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible for the parent page to: fill in the Name Textbox and run the function of the create button inside the iframe?

Comment: Sure, use Script Editor and insert code:
<iframe src="https://SP.sharepoint.com/teams/apps/_layouts/15/new.aspx?FeatureId=%7B00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100%7D&ListTemplate=100&IsDlg=1" width="600" height="200">
</iframe>
with URL:https://SP.sharepoint.com/teams/apps you are defining where the list will be created. 
Select my Answer as solution, if it fits your request :) Thanks

Comment: did my answer help you? mark it as answer, thanks :)